# Как изменить данные в data() при клике на элемент в v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Недавно начал изучать vue, но столкнулся с проблемой: перебирая в v-for компонент и вешая на этот компонент слушатель я надеюсь "выбрать" этот элемент, поместив в *activeItem* id карточки, на которую кликнули, но в итоге при клике ничего не меняется.
**Код основного компонента**:

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
    <Cards :Card="card" @click="this.activeItem = card.id"></Cards>
  </div>

</template>


<script>
import Cards from "@/components/Cards";
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Cards
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [
        {id: 1, name: 'first', description: 'card 1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'second', description: 'card 2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'third', description: 'card 3'}
      ],
      activeItem: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Вот код компонента карточки:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{Card.id}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{Card.name}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 
  name: 'Cards',
  props: {
    Card: Object,
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не вставляйте в Code Snippet код, который не запускается, только если ваш вопрос связан с самой ошибкой, который возникает при запуске

Comment: @EzioMercer спасибо, учту. Первый раз оставляю вопрос с кодом, поэтому первым же возможным способом его вставил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вешаете обработчик на пользовательский компонент, поэтому именно этот компонент и должен заниматься генерированием события с помощью встроенного метода [$emit](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit), передавая ему имя события.

В вашем случае достаточно добавить в компонент обработчик на верхний элемент и с помощью `$emit('click')` вызвать метод, который был передан из родительского компонента и в качестве первого аргумента можете передать `id` вашей карточки:

```
 <div @click="$emit('click', card.id)">
```

Учтите также, что каждый компонент `Vue` должен содержать [один корневой элемент](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82):

```
<template>
  <div>
   <div>
     {{Card.id}}
   </div>
   <div>
     {{Card.name}}
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
const card = Vue.component = {
  name: 'card',
  props: {
    card: Object,
  },
  template: `
  <div @click="$emit('click', card.id)">
    <div>
      {{card.id}}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{card.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
`
}
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    card
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'first',
          description: 'card 1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'second',
          description: 'card 2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'third',
          description: 'card 3'
        }
      ],
      activeItem: 0,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    activeItem = {{ activeItem }}
  </p>
  <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
    <Card :Card="card" @click="(val) => activeItem = val"></Card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Второй вариант - использовать [нативные события](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85), применив модификатор `.native` для директивы `v-on`:

```
@click.native="activeItem = card.id"
```

```js
const card = Vue.component = {
  name: 'card',
  props: {
    card: Object,
  },
  template: `
  <div>
    <div>
      {{card.id}}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{card.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
`
}
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    card
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'first',
          description: 'card 1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'second',
          description: 'card 2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'third',
          description: 'card 3'
        }
      ],
      activeItem: 0,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    activeItem = {{ activeItem }}
  </p>
  <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
    <Card :Card="card" @click.native="activeItem = card.id"></Card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример для `Vue 3` (все за исключением синтаксиса тоже, только в дочернем компоненте нужно подписаться на событие `click`, как `emits: ['click'],`):

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      cards: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'first',
          description: 'card 1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'second',
          description: 'card 2'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'third',
          description: 'card 3'
        }
      ],
      activeItem: 0,
    }
  },
})

app.component('card', {
  props: {
    card: Object,
  },
  emits: ['click'],
  template: `
  <div @click="$emit('click', card.id)">
    <div>
      {{card.id}}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{card.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
`
})

app.mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    activeItem = {{ activeItem }}
  </p>
  <div v-for="card in cards" :key="card.id">
    <Card :Card="card" @click="(val) => activeItem = val"></Card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Смысл я понял. Единственное что, я правильно полагаю, что так или иначе придётся задействовать модификатор `native`, так как в обоих примерах он использован?

Comment: Я посмотрел историю изменений. Как я понимаю, в первом примере при клике должен срабатывать такой вызов '(val) => this.activeItem = val'. Ещё раз благодарю за ответ, очень выручили!

Comment: Да, все верно, первый вариант будет работать и без модификатора, это я, подготавливая второй вариант кода, машинально добавил модификатор в первый)

Comment: Понял, ешё раз благодарю!

Comment: Попробовал сейчас вставить ответ в свой код, но получился странный ответ, вместо значения выводит '[object MouseEvent]'. При этом ваш пример при запуске срабатывает идеально.  Видимо, из-за разных версий Vue. Не знаете, как исправить?

Comment: какую версию используете?

Comment: Третью. 3.2.13, если быть точнее

Comment: Удалось решить вопрос. Видимо, в третьей версии нельзя использовать `$emit('click')`. После замены `'click'` на `'chooseActive'` как в `$emit`, так и в атрибуте корневого компонента всё заработало

Comment: дополнил ответ для `vue 3`

Comment: Вижу, теперь даже c `@click`ом всё рабоатет на ура в третьей версии! Теперь точно всё работает, ещё раз спасибо!